# Prevent code from being executed after forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently trying to achieve a simple CRUD operation in ReactJS + ExpressJS. I have an async onSubmit method that handles form submitting.

The `foreach` loop below should contain some array element checks and if the anonymous function returns false, the application should exit the `onSubmit`, but the `try-catch` block manages to get executed before the `foreach` finishes.

Since I don't have anything to really `await` in my `foreach` loop, is there a way to "await" until it fully finishes and the execute code that is inside the `try-catch` block while keeping the `onSubmit` method asynchronous?

```js
    onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (something) {
                return false;
        }

        // This foreach gets executed after the try-catch below, but I want it to execute first
        someArr.forEach(item => {
            if (item.arr === undefined || item.arr.length == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        try {
            // This has some await axios.post() calls...
        } catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` statement inside the `forEach` callback does not prevent try catch evaluation because that `return` statement is inside the callback, so it returns from the callback instead of the outer `onSubmit` function.

If I understand correctly the intention is to return from `onSubmit` if any item in the array meets the condition:
`(item.arr === undefined || item.arr.length == 0)`

If that's correct, you can rewrite it using [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (something) {
    return false;
  }

  const shouldReturn = someArr.some(item => item.arr === undefined || item.arr.length === 0);

  if (shouldReturn) {
    return;
  }

  try {
    // This has some await axios.post() calls...
  } catch { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Something came onto my mind afterwards. If I had another array inside the `item.arr`, would the a nested `some` approach be any good?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, if there is an array inside an array item and you need to apply similar validation - nested `some` may be a way to go. If the code gets overcomplicated with that, you can define a callback passed to `some` in the outer scope (instead of defining it inline as an anonymous function) in order to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to why you should not be able to perform all of the logic inside of the try-catch block give this a try.

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (something) {
            return false;
    }

    try {
        let should_call = true;
        someArr.forEach(item => {
          if (item.arr === undefined || item.arr.length == 0) {
            should_call false;
          }
        });

        if(should_call){
           // Call has some await axios.post() calls...
        }

    } catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The forEach loop is already synchronous. Here's a modification of your method that demonstrates this:

```
onSubmit = async () => {
    const someArr = []
    for(let i=0; i<100; i++){
        someArr.push(i);
    }

    someArr.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(`forEach: ${item}`);

    });

    try {
        console.log(`try block`);

    } catch { }
}

onSubmit();
```

Comment: The try block can still get executed before the forEach finishes, though. In case I wasn't clear earlier, I want to leave the `onSubmit` method if my `if-statement` in the `forEach` returns false. The answer @antonku provided seems to be a nice approach.

Comment: I understand, but to be clear, this has nothing to do with the forEach loop not being synchronous. @antonku's answer is good.